# Discord.js How do i make an embed goes to a specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm new to coding and this might be a stupid question. But how do I make an embed like this go to a channel with an id for an example I want the embed to go to a channel with id "746423099871985755"

```
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("746423099871985755");
channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

This will send the embed into the channel with the ID `746423099871985755`.